# Magento update limit at 1095?

Tags: magento, sql-update, magento-1.7

Hi I am running a script to update all the backorders and in_stock for my clients products.
Currently we have about 8700 products. However, I noticed when I try to call the function to update it all, it seems to redirect to 500 internal server error.

I did a collection count and set a limit to see where the break off point was - 1095.

So anything more than 1095 products and it just fails.

I am using Magento Community Edition 1.7.0.2

/// Codes below

```
umask(0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin');   


$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

# Magento SQL queries


$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1096);
$collection->addFieldToFilter(array(
 array('attribute'=>'preorder', 'eq'=>'1'),

)); 

echo $collection->count();
die();
foreach ($collection as $product) {

    #echo $product->getData('sku')." - ".$product->getData('name')." with preorder status of - ".$product->getData('preorder')."<br/>" ;

    $sku = $product->getData('sku');
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);


    $stock->setBackorders("2");
    $stock->setUse_config_backorders("0");
    $stock->setIs_in_stock("1");
    $stock->save();

    echo $product->getData('sku')." - ".$product->getData('name')." with backorder status of - ".$stock->getData('backorders')." - Use config? - ".$stock->getData('use_config_backorders')." is in stock ? - ".$stock->getData('is_in_stock')."<br/>" ;
    #die();
}
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you,

Julian

Comment: are you sure, you don't hit the max_execution_time?

Comment: same question for the memory_limit ?

Comment: stick this at the top:
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); ini_set('display_errors', 1); set_time_limit(0);

Comment: why are you setting a limit in your collection? $collection->getSelect()->limit(1096); 0-1095 ID is indeed 1096....